# What are some good resources for sailing in Greece?

Tags: online-resources, planning, itineraries, islands, sailing

I will be sailing in Greece for two weeks later this summer. The trip is lead by an experienced captain, but I'm looking for good resources to help me prepare. Specifically, I'm interested in resources specific to sailing the Greek Isles, not sailing in general. Unfortunately, what I'm finding in my own searches is a lot of charter websites.

I'm looking for information on the many Greek islands, recommended routes, weather patterns, boating regulations, recommendations/advice when sailing the Greek isles, etc.

Found so far:

- [Cruiserswiki.org](http://www.cruiserswiki.org/wiki/Greece)
- [greeksails.com](http://www.greeksails.com/en_GB/sailing-holiday-greece/what-to-bring-sailing/)
- [Sailingissues.com](http://www.sailingissues.com/greek.html)

**Update**

Additional finds since the original post.

- [Greek Waters Pilot: A Yachtsmans Guide to the Ionian and Aegean Coasts and the Islands of Greece](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1846233348) - £30.80
- [Cruising the Islands of Greece](http://cruises.about.com/cs/europeancruises/a/greekisles.htm)
- [Sailing Areas in Greece - Brief Description](http://www.easysailing.gr/Sailing_Greece-article11-p1.phtml) - [PDF table breakdown](http://www.easysailing.gr/pdf/sailing.areas.comparison.pdf)
- [The Greek Islands, New ed.](http://amzn.com/0756626374)
- [The Rough Guide To Greece](http://amzn.com/1848367279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm far from being an expert in sailing, but being a native speaker helps when searching so this is what I came across:

[A 13 page guide in English from visitgreece.gr](http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Nautical_eng.pdf) (PDF, 24.4 MB)

CONTENTS

- Introduction
- Sail the Ionian Sea
- Sail around Peloponnese and Kythira
- Sail around Attica and Saronikos Gulf
- Sail through the Cyclades
- Sail through the Sporades
- Sail the North Aegean Sea
- Sail around the Dodecanese
- Sail around Crete
- Discover a variety of water sports activities
- Useful Information

It's not very detailed, but a good starting point I reckon.

Enjoy your holiday!

Answer (score 5):

A very useful mobile guide to use, both for planning and while sailing in Greece, is **Sail-Pilot**. It is a complete **Greek Waters Pilot**, being authorised by the **Hellenic Navy Hydrographic Service**. It is a mobile app available for iPhone and Android platforms, with specific layouts for smartphone and tablet devices. It includes the official Sailing Directions for the Greek Waters, which are being updated every year with the latest notices to mariners. You may find more info here:

http://sail-pilot.com

The app includes nine libraries for the Sailing Areas that you may purchase separately from the app stores through the app:

- Cyclades Islands Sailing Area
- Ionian Islands Sailing Area
- Dodecanese Sailing Area
- Saronic Islands Sailing Area
- Sporades Sailing Area
- Myrtoan Sea Sailing Area
- North East Aegean Sailing Area
- Crete Sailing Area
- Corinthian Gulf Sailing Area

The price of the libraries spans from 7.99 € to 17.99 € (ex. VAT).

If you are considering sailing in more than two Sailing Areas, it is more economic to download the [Sail-Pilot Plus](http://hartis.org/p/1272/SAILPILOT_Plus_Mobile_Greek_Waters_Pilot) app that includes all Sailing Areas and purchase one license for 49.99 € (inc. VAT).

The Sail-Pilot team of specialists, which I belong to, assists sailors **free of charge** with planning their Sailing Holiday in Greece.

Answer (score 3):

A relatively complete guide for sailing in Greece is the Discover phase of the **Sail-la-Vie.com** platform, which includes more than 4.000 points of interest within the Greek Archipelago:

[Sail-la-vie.com](http://www.sail-la-vie.com/discover/sailing-in-Greece)

The Greek Archipelago is divided in 9 Sailing Areas:

- Cyclades
- Ionian Islands
- Dodecanese
- Saronic Islands
- Sporades
- Myrtoan Sea (South & East Peloponnese)
- Crete
- Corinthian Gulf
- Northeast Aegean

and using the map layout you can drill down quickly to the area you want to sail and find info related to harbours, coves, beaches, diving centres, caves, as well as for things to do while being onshore during holidays (cultural events, restaurants, bars and many more). For every island the platform suggests **nautical charts** of the specific sailing area and **hiking maps** for onshore excursions.

The Sail la Vie platform provides a tool for planning sailing routes. You can plan your own route, by selecting points of interest from the Discover phase. During the Plan phase you can then place them on the route map, change their order and built your sailing route very easily by dragging the waypoints to the desired position.

At the end of the Plan phase of sail-la-vie.com/plan you have the option to download the waypoints as gpx file. Beyond planning your own route, Sail la Vie also suggests more than **30 itineraries** around the sailing areas of the Greek Archipelago, which you may also download in gpx format.

The Sail la Vie team, that I belong to, is online most of the time and provides assistance with the route planning, as well as useful sailing tips -

[Sail-la-vie.com](http://sail-la-vie.com/info/about-sail-la-vie-enjoy-sailing-in-Greece)